# SignalR notification not showing to all clients

Tags: asp.net, signalr

Here is the Hub Class

```
public class NotificationHub:Hub
    {
        public void Hello(string msg)
        {
            Clients.All.helloEveryone(msg);
        }
    }
```

Button Click for server side call in the document.ready function

```
   $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#setnotification').click(function () {
                    var notifier = $.connection.notificationHub;
                    notifier.server.hello('World!');
                });
```

And here is the call to all clients

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var notifier = $.connection.notificationHub;
        notifier.client.helloEveryone = function (msg) {
            $('#chatWindow').text(msg);
        }
</script>
```

But the problem is When I have two browsers Opened I can see that only active browser shows the notification.Not Another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20-and-mvc-5

You will notice you are binding your JavaScript client object each time the button is clicked which most likely is causing issues. Recommend having a look at how the example at this URL instantiates the client side and go from there. Notice they perform the $.connection.hub.start() in document ready, not for each chat request

Is the problem with declaring the same variable name notifier in both the button click event and in global scope? Depending on where your code sits in the DOM, you should be able to just change the line in setnotification client to notifer.server.hello to get it to work. Just call the global notifier declared in your DOM. Don't reestablish a connection
This could work as just a simple example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var notifier = $.connection.notificationHub;
    notifier.client.helloEveryone = function (msg) {
        $('#chatWindow').text(msg);
    });
    $(function(){
        notifier.start().done(function(){
            $("#setnotification").click(function(){
                notifier.server.hello('World!');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please see edited answer - notifier name conflict. Sorry made mistake in answer fix. Just use global notifier variable already declared in DOM

Comment: great, it worked.But the problem is my set notification button and show notification button is not in the same dom.That means my set notification but show notification is in different view not in same view.+1 for help and will accept it if you show me the way

Comment: how can they not be in the same DOM? sorry not sure what u mean by that